# Why is the answer ALWAYS reinstall Windows

Tags: windows-explorer, unresponsive

Anytime there's an issue the general answer is always try a fresh install or restore from last saved recovery?

Should't software be better by now?

Rather adding more and/or different options why not fix the basics first?

... many computers ... many configurations...
isn't that what Certified Microsoft drivers/software are supposed to do?

Just a rant, as Windows is becoming ever increasing problemic rather than just running while being left alone?

Answer (score 2):

#### Why is the answer ALWAYS reinstall Windows

Your question is too broad.

There are plenty of accepted answers for Windows questions on this site that **do not** require the re-installation of Windows.